# Is defining (full replete sub) categories using "set-builder notation" evil?

Tags: category-theory

This is not actually my situtation, but here is an example of what I mean:
Let $C$ be any category, and $V \in C$. Then I define a category $\text{MP}_V$ with

- objects: $X \in \text{MP}_V$ iff there is a monomorphism $X \to Y \times V$ in $C$, for some $Y \in C$ (this presupposes of course the existence of the product, which I have not necessarily assumed)
- morphisms: $\text{MP}_V (X, Y) = C(X, Y)$

My (admittedly vague) question is if `picking objects' like this is really a well-defined operation, or if there's some subtlety I have to watch out for.
I don't really know what irks me about it, since I see things like this all the time in papers, but something makes me feel uncomfortable.

I guess what makes this definition well-defined is that my category up there is actually defined in an invariant-under-isomorphisms way, i.e. $X \in \text{MP}_V$ and $X \cong Y$ in $C$ implies $Y \in \text{MP}_V$.
So $\text{MP}_V$ may actually be viewed as full replete subcategory of $C$.

(Sorry if this is all really vague, but I never really cared about the principle of equivalence before, so I'm really unsure about things here)

Comment: There's no problem with it: you can consider any subclass of the class of objects (need not be closed under isomorphism) and take the full subcategory on that.

Comment: @Berci: Thanks, I think my real problem is that I do not fully understand size issues, and thus I am always weirded out by vaguely set-theoretic operations, not knowing which is permitted and which not. Something to brush up on :)